# Which version of Eclipse works with OS X 10.4.11?

Tags: eclipse, macos, ide

I'm using a pretty old machine (iBook G4), and I want to install Eclipse with PyDev for my coding. Which version of Eclipse would work with my OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse Ganymede definitely works with your version, at least that was the last version I used back in the days on that OS.
However, I don't see any reason why even the newest version wouldn't run so I'd say just try the newest release (Indigo).

Comment: Thanks! I tried installing the latest, but it seems my OS is too old.